# Правильная запись синтаксисом Objective-C

Tags: xcode, objective-c

в программе пишу строку которая меняет булево значение на противоположное.

```
 someObject.boolValue = ![someObject boolValue];
```

Каким образом можно записать правильно (без дот-синтаксиса) левую часть выражения. То есть используя только квадратные скобки?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно так

```
[someObject setBoolValue:![someObject boolValue]];
```

Но лучше это как-то заменить на отдельный метод, который будет работать с внутренней переменной, потому что в вашем примере отсылается два сообщения (setter + getter), хотя можно обойтись и одним.

Comment: 1101_debian, большое спасибо, все верно!